# tooltip problem in dhtmlxscheduler

Tags: javascript, scheduler, dhtmlx

I'm currently using dhtmlx scheduler (http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml). I'm using its tooltip plugins and expand plugins. When the scheduler is small size or is placed in the document's specific DIV then the tooltip does not show in correct position. But when we expand it the tooltip is OK.

Is there any solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxscheduler:known_issues